# Archlinux: Genymotion won't start device

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion, archlinux

I installed Genymotion on archlinux, after system update Genymotion devices won't start. 
When I start the device from virtualbox, I saw this issue:
[device issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6LBn.png)

**Edit:**
I tried to reinstall virtualbox and genymotion but I still have the same problem

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by desintalling and reinstalling the nvidia driver.